# How can I prove that the open interval $(c,d)$ is not of measure zero?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am currently trying to prove this theorem. I know how to do the closed interval case, it is a contradiction proof that uses the heine-borel theorem. Does anyone know how I can do the open interval case? I suspect it uses contradiction too, but dont know where to obtain the contradiction from (in closed case it was from the heine-borel theorem).

Thanks!

Comment: You asked this question less than $2$ hours after you previously asked it, and received two answers. Instead of re-asking, comment or edit to clarify the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** If $(a,b)$ is measure zero, then $[a,b]=(a,b)\cup\{a,b\}$ is also measure zero.

Comment: Or, choose $c', d'$ with $c < c' < d' < d$ and show $[c',d']$ is not of measure zero.